# How to determine source of git conflict in destination branch?

Tags: git

In my workflow, I'll create a pull request to merge my `some_feature_fix` branch into an upstream `staging` branch. In some pull request web UIs, if there's a conflict, it'll say which file contains the conflict, but often times won't say what lines or what its source branch is.

This makes resolving the conflict difficult, because I can't simply merge in `staging` since that would make my branch dependent on any other branches also on staging, which might later get pulled off if they fail QA. The solution is I need to contact the developer of the conflicting branch and work out the details some other way, either by ensuring their branch gets approved on staging, or removed so my branch can get merged in.

However, if I need to hunt down the developer of the source branch, I have to scroll through `git log` on the conflicting file, and manually check every branch name in the log to find the source branch, so I can work out the details with the other developer.

This is very time consuming and frustrating. Is there a programmatic way to do it more efficiently? Something like:

```
$ git checkout staging
$ git pull
$ git checkout some_feature_fix
$ find_conflicting_source_branch.sh staging
other_fix
```

Comment: Is `staging` a "temporary" integration branch that is periodically reset to a long lived branch? (This would be like the `next` branch in [gitworkflow](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_branch_management_for_next_and_seen_after_a_feature_release).)

Comment: Another way to word my previous question would be: is `staging` ever merged into another long lived branch? (e.g. `master`, `main`, `prod`, etc.) Or are all feature branches that are merged into `staging`, once validated, separately merged into the long lived branch such as `main`?

Comment: do you know the lines where the conflict occurs? You can `git checkout staging` and `git blame <file>` to see who changes those lines most recently.

Comment: There is [`git merge-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree), whose purpose is to have git compute a merge without modifying the index or the worktrees. You can read the list of conflicting files (if there are any) from its output.

Comment: BTW, my previous comments are hinting at the idea that a workflow tweak might help you more than determining which previous feature branch conflicts with your branch. Either the other feature branch is staying, or is getting pulled out (in which case it should have been pulled out already), or they don't know yet. And you having a conflict may not help the other developer suddenly "know" if it's staying or going. My suggestion would be to always assume it's staying and resolve the conflict on a new temp branch. And reset `staging` periodically to the permanent "good" branch (e.g. `main`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the files that have conflicts in the moment you try to merge it.
I you merge two branchs, and there's conflic git shows them with 'both modified', and in red, then you only need to open the file and search for the conflict, the part between '<<<<<' and '>>>>>'.

```
$ git checkout staging
$ git pull
$ git checkout some_feature_fix
$ git merge --no-ff staging
# here if there's conflicts you see the files wich need to be checked.
$ git push -u origin some_feature_fix
```

In the case you don't want to merge staging in your branch, you can create an intermediate one from your branch, merge there and solve the conflicts.

```
$ git checkout staging
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b staging_solve_conflicts
$ git merge --no-ff some_feature_fix
# solve conflicts
$ git checkout staging
$ git merge --no-ff staging_solve_conflicts
```

Comment: You misunderstand me. I know how to do a simple merge and resolve conflicts. In my example, I don't know that `some_feature_fix` is the source of the conflict. That's what I'm trying to find. It's obfuscated by being merged into `staging`, which is also my push destination.